# How to count the number of different colors from a video?

Tags: windows, video, colors

I would like a software that could allow the user to **count the number of different colors used in a video** (mp4/avi/mpeg2) for comparison purposes of colors palette.

Windows and/or linux

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found one:

https://github.com/koenig-sebastian/VideoColorAnalysis

VideoColorAnalysis

[image]